# Full screen gif with scroll, Like parallax video effect

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a parallax effect for a web page. 
At the top of the page i want a gif to show in full screen.

[Like this link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-2.php)

but i dont want it to be fixed. I want it to scroll like normal. 
When i start scrolling it needs to cut out right away, regardless of the height og the gif.

My problem is to get rid of the "fixed" but keep the same function.

```
    #bg {
        position:fixed; 
        top:-50%; 
        left:-50%; 
        width:200%; 
        height:200%;
    }
    #bg img {
        position:absolute; 
        top:0; 
        left:0; 
        right:0; 
        bottom:0; 
        margin:auto; 
        min-width:50%;
        min-height:50%;
    }



<div id="bg">
    <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean? You want bg to take up 100% height and 100% width at the top of the page but not be fixed?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/29/18/47/nature-3048299__340.jpg);
}

.spacer {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes almost right!
The gif now fills the page perfect as i want it too.
But it repeats itself, instead of being one big gif.

Comment: @perand add `background-size: cover;` to bg. Be aware that if your image is small it will appear with terrible resolution.

Comment: Thanks almost there. 
Is there a way to center the gif?
instead of getting stuck to the left?

Comment: @perand could you screenshot? Not sure what that means :p

Comment: jepp, like this:
Purple is now, but i want it to be like the blue.
Where the black dot is always center.

https://imgur.com/a/rAm4q9H

Comment: when scaling the screen

Comment: @perand try adding `background-position: center center;` to your .bg

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! thanks for all help, you are a genius!

Comment: No worries mate, remember to mark as answer please. @perand